# Should I include a link to my Stack Overflow profile on my résumé?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, contribution, cv

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, how ever it is related with Stackoverflow (and me).

Recently, I had a chance to talk with Team manager in mobile company which name is irrelevant. He was asking me what I do, what do I study etc. I showed him some of my applications and he offered me to send him my CV or résumé ASAP.

I'm writing my CV right now. I have a paragraph where I state my contributions and projects, I wonder would it be good idea if I add my contribution towards StackOverflow community I do in free time? Would I exaggerate things? Will that information be relevant, regardless of my point of view and reckoning towards it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it okay to use my stack overflow answers as examples of my coding-style and communication skills; on job interviews](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41038/is-it-okay-to-use-my-stack-overflow-answers-as-examples-of-my-coding-style-and-co), [Stack Overflow Careers success stories?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35013/stack-overflow-careers-success-stories), [Is Stack Overflow reputation marketable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30578/), [Has your StackOverflow reputation helped your career?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30615/)

Comment: the given link in the closed question is broken! The page is not available

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We covered this in detail [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12070/would-you-put-your-stackoverflow-profile-link-on-your-cv-resume) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9948/how-to-sell-a-high-so-reputation-at-an-interview) on Programmers SE. I'll copy my own answer to the first question below.

---

**It Depends**

When I was looking for a job a [few months] ago, I didn't put a link to SO on my resume, but I did mention that I participate on SO and added a link to my blog that contains the SO "flair" on the About page. At that point I had about 3000 rep.

I wouldn't try to leverage rep, but I would leverage intelligent participation. If you act like a moron on SO and draw attention to it, that's obviously a bad move. But if you say "hey, I participate on this dedicated Q&A site" and you have been giving good answers and asking smart questions, it can work in your favour as it shows passion for your work and fellow developers.