# What can stackexchange do for me professionally

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

Am on askubuntu and love to contribute there, and other stackexchange sites. I was wondering on how can I use stackexchange(askubuntu) for my professional reputation.

How plausible is it for me to use stackexcange on my C.V., how can i use stackexcange to show my employer my competence.

<sup>English is not my native language</sup>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I include a link to my Stack Overflow profile on my résumé?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100217/should-i-include-a-link-to-my-stack-overflow-profile-on-my-resume) and of [Is Stack Overflow reputation marketable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30578/is-stack-overflow-reputation-marketable)

Comment: @AlienArrays, i already know what i can do for stackexchange :)

Comment: Also see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/9948/285

Comment: Also see [Should I include information about my reputation on professionally-relevant Stack Exchange (or other Q&A) sites on my resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/308/168) at Workplace.SE