# Can we say Stack Overflow a Professional/Technical Society?

Tags: discussion

The [tour page of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) says that

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack
>   Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together
>   to build a library of detailed answers to every question about
>   programming.

Since the above description says it is a site for **professional** programmers, and we have a lot of people here as well (which makes a society :P), so can we say it is a **Professional Society**?

Definition of a Professional Society (According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_association)):

> A professional association (also called a professional body,
>   professional organization, or professional society) is usually a
>   nonprofit organization seeking to further a particular profession, the
>   interests of individuals engaged in that profession and the public
>   interest.

(If you have any of your own definitions for a **Professional Society**, that will work as well)

P.S. I was doing my resume and I have to answer some predefined questions, one of those is **Professional Societies**, so I was wondering if I can write about Stack Overflow there? Since I have been answering a few questions recently and reading a lot as well.

Thanks for looking into the question! :D

Comment: Bah, my first thoughts were the question in the title is attempted with a sarcastic tone and the body of the Q is a rant. :p

Comment: I can't really answer this question without knowing what a "professional society" is (it appears to have a highly specific meaning, given the fact that you bolded it every time you mentioned it...). Can you define, or link to, your definition of "**Professional Society**"?

Comment: @Shokhet Well, I am not sure about it either, and neither are a lot of people around me. I am a college student! So, I am assuming that the professional society would be student group or stuff.. We have a lot of Tech Societies in our college, so people are writing about those Tech Societies in the column for professional Society!

Comment: Let me get this straight. You don't *know* what a "Professional Society" is, and you're asking is SO is one? I'm sorry, but I'll have to vote to close as unclear, as the question is pretty much unanswerable (at least until you pick a well-defined definition)

Comment: @Shokhet Well wikipedia says this "A professional association (also called a professional body, professional organization, or professional society) is usually a nonprofit organization seeking to further a particular profession, the interests of individuals engaged in that profession and the public interest." So, following this definition I think the answer shall be yes?

Comment: ....so you *do* have a definition you'd like to use?

Comment: I think ***community** of professional programmers* is more descriptive.

Comment: Question edited, close vote retracted.

Comment: Professional… and enthusiast.

Comment: I don't think that allowing each answerer their own definition of "professional society" is okay, because how are you (and us, those who vote on the answers) supposed to know if a specific answer has answered the question?

Comment: @Shokhet Yeah! You are right. But I am also looking for some other views!  Just in case anyone else had a different view to a professional society during their college, because the definition isn't mine anyway, but somehow fits.

Comment: Funny how you managed to completely ignore the two words following "professional" there. Namely **and enthusiast**.

Comment: @Oded Had I ignored it, I won't have asked a question here .. :P

Comment: I found the word "enthusiast" to be conspicuous by absence, in particular given how much bold "professional" got...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the definition of "Professional Society" that you cited from Wikipedia, SO is **not** a professional society, because the purpose is not to further the profession of programming (which would mean forming a union for programmers and similar things), but rather a question and answer website for the purpose of answering questions about programming.

As for your resume, I'm under the impression that many programmers link to their SO profile in their resume, so there's certainly nothing wrong with that...I'm just not sure that it can be included under "professional societies."

See [At what point do you put your SO reputation in your resume?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58947/266359), [Should I include a link to my Stack Overflow profile on my résumé?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100217/266359), [Is Stack Overflow reputation marketable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30578/266359), [Can Stack Overflow reputation be used on resumes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64416/266359), and [Have you ever used your gained reputation points to get a job or something?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25453/266359) for more info. (*see also the numerous linked questions in the comments under some of those questions*)

Comment: Thanks.. :D The links made it more clear. :)